# Windows: Strange behaviour when pressing C key

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

So when pressing the C key on a windows 7 64bit laptop I get 4 short beeps from the system and some really strange output on the screen. This makes it almost impossible for the user of the laptop to fill in passwords on websites since he often uses a password with the character C in it. Here's an example of what happens when entering superuser.com:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the keyboard has gone bad.  On most laptops, it's relatively easy to replace the keyboard.  Unfortunately, it generally isn't cheap as most laptop keyboards are integrated with the touchpad.  It's pretty easy to verify that it is a keyboard problem.  Boot into the command prompt rather than windows and just try typing at the prompt.  If the C key does not work correctly there either, the keyboard is broken.  This happened on my work laptop a few years ago.  Took about 5 minutes to replace the keyboard, but the tech that brought me the new keyboard told me they paid close to $100 for each one.  Depending on the model, you may be able to find a replacement online for cheaper.

Comment: I guess it is yeah. I have booted into command prompt safe mode and although I don't get any beeps it still displays the strange output on the screen... I will call the manufacturer to see what we can do about this. Laptop is only 2 months old... Thank you for your reply BBlake! I will mark it as accepted ;)

Comment: The easiest way to test is to substitute a known working keyboard and see what you get.

Comment: Hmm I won't open the laptop myself, I don't think that would be good for it ;) But I have called the manufacturer and they agree with us that the keyboard is broken. They say the beeps are warning us that the contact points are broken and that when I press the C it also sends a signal to other keys. So we gonna send the laptop in for repair ;)